# simple JS regex to extract word between parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I would need a regex to extract 'Fred' (identified as user) from a string like

```
var s='city(NewYork)country(USA)user(Fred)age(30)'
```

tried this not working

```
s.match(/(user\()\w+/)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the parens. Unless you're 100% certain that `s` is a string, you should prefer [`/.../.exec(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) over [`string.match(regex)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3S6cV/

```
var match = s.match(/user\((\w+)\)/);
if (match) {
    match = match[1];
} else {
    match = "Not Found!";
}
```

Comment: @ca11111 Use `[1]`, as in my example.

Comment: your ex not wworking, putted right one in 1st comment, thanks

Comment: @ca11111 I have added a demo link to my answer, which shows that the code is working. What code are you using?

Comment: sorry Could I ask you how to maker it work with more than 1 word, ex var s='city(NewYork)country(USA)user(Fred Macguire)age(30)'

Comment: get all alpha,umerics characters between the brackets, something like s.match(/user\(([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\)/); but it's not mworking, should give 'fred Macguire'

Comment: @ca11111 Use `[^)]+` instead of `\w+` (spaces are not alphanumeric, hence they aren't matched by `\w`. `[^)]+` means: "Eveyr non-) character).